# Can I deploy an HTML5 application using the WebAppRT executable?

Tags: html, firefox, web-applications, deployment

I see that the lastest versions of Firefox come with a webapprt.exe and webapprt-stub.exe executable. I think that they are for the Open Web Apps system but I would like to know if it's possible to use the WebAppRT container with external made applications. I mean that I could distribute the WebAppRT executable, the shared libs required and my HTML files and deploy it offline without having Firefox installed.

Answer (score 0):

### Why?

What do you mean by "external made applications"?

Why don't you just create a web app as explained in  [Building Web apps - App Center | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build) ?

It will take care of the details and allow your app to reach more platform than doing it manually. For a glance see [Platform-specific details of app installation - App Center | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Platform-specific_details)

> You don't have to do anything special to install apps on different platforms. All the information you need to provide, such as the app name, is contained in the app manifest. Here are some platform-specific details about how apps are installed on each platform. These details assume that Firefox has been installed on the platform.

To make that path easier, you can follow tutorials or clone an existing open-source web app that has something in common to see how it's done.

### What did you mean?

If you mean to just manually locally install a some app that you write, the simplest thing to do would be to install any app, look at what's been done and replicate the steps with your app.  But what's the point?

My guess is: it will work only if the local OS has a platform to actually execute the app.  Then that platform will also be able to install the app properly.  So, it will be simpler to you to just make a regular web app and have it installed through standard means.

Or were you thinking of something else?